# how retrieve array returned by config in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

How I can get the array returned by config/autoload in zend framework 2?

```
#config/autoload/myconfig.local.php

return array('foo' => 'bar');
```

I noticed if the file have not "return array()" an exception will throw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This config is merged automatically in the whole app config. You can get this by calling

`$sl->get('config')`

on your ServiceManager. There will be all the config you have.